# Set and Get @property method in Python by string variable

Tags: python, attributes, descriptor

Currently I have a generalized function where you can pass in an attribute name and a class (it would also work with specific object instances, but I am using classes), and the function will look up and operate on that attribute by calling

```
getattr(model_class, model_attribute)
```

and it will modify the attribute by calling (on an object instance this time)

settattr(model_obj, key, value)

However, I have a class where we have an `@property` method defined instead of a simple attribute, and `setattr` does not work. How do I dynamically get the `@property` based on a string name for that property method?

Perhaps I could use `__dict__` but that seems dirty and not as safe.

Edit: example code

The generalized function

```
def process_general(mapping, map_keys, model_class, filter_fn, op_mode=op_modes.UPDATE):
    """
    Creates or updates a general table object based on a config dictionary.

    `mapping`: a configuration dictionary, specifying info about the table row value
    `map_keys`: keys in the mapping that we use for the ORM object
    `model_class`: the ORM model class we use the config data in
    `op_mode`: the kind of operation we want to perform (delete, update, add, etc.)

    Note that relationships between model objects must be defined and connected
    outside of this function.
    """
    # We construct a dictionary containing the values we need to set
    arg_dict = make_keyword_args(map_keys, mapping)

    # if we are updating, then we must first check if the item exists
    # already
    if (op_mode == op_modes.UPDATE):
        # Find all rows that match by the unique token.
        # It should only be one, but we will process all of them if it is the
        # case that we didn't stick to the uniqueness requirement.
        matches = filter_fn()

        # Keep track of the length of the iterator so we know if we need to add
        # a new row
        num_results = 0
        for match in matches:
            # and we set all of the object attributes based on the dictionary
            set_attrs_from_dict(match, arg_dict)
            model_obj = match
            num_results += 1
        # We have found no matches, so just add a new row
        if (num_results < 1):
            model_obj = model_class(**arg_dict)

        return model_obj

    # TODO add support for other modes. This here defaults to add
    else:
        return model_class(**arg_dict)
```

An example class passed in:

```
class Dataset(db.Model, UserContribMixin):
    # A list of filters for the dataset. It can be built into the dataset filter form dict
    # in get_filter_form. It's also useful for searching.
    filters     = db.relationship('DatasetFilter', backref='dataset')

    # private, and retrieved from the @property = select
    _fact_select = db.relationship('DatasetFactSelect', order_by='DatasetFactSelect.order')

    @property
    def fact_select(self):
        """
        FIXME: What is this used for?

        Appears to be a list of strings used to select (something) from the
        fact model in the star dataset interface.

        :return: List of strings used to select from the fact model
        :rtype: list
        """

        # these should be in proper order from the relationship order_by clause
        sels = [sel.fact_select for sel in self._fact_select]
        return sels
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a class and a call to your function, and explain how this doesn't give what you want? `getattr` handles properties as transparently as the `.` syntax, so I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Actually, before you go through any pains to answer this, let me snoop around in my code more. I thought the issue was that `getattr` did not work for properties, but if it should work, then I'm sure that the error lies somewhere else. I can clear more stuff up and maybe even find the solution.

Comment: hasattr,setattr and getattr works in my code. but i declared it as `request = property(get_request, set_request, del_request)`

Comment: So, I wrote part of the question wrong. `setattr` does not work for the property. In this specific case, we are trying to set the property to `None`.

Comment: If you are trying to set the property, why not add a `setter` method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Calling `getattr(model_class, model_attribute)` will return the property object that `model_attribute` refers to. I'm assuming  you already know this and are trying to access the value of the property object.

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._myprop = "Hello"

    @property
    def myprop(self):
        return self._myprop

    @myprop.setter
    def myprop(self, v):
        self._myprop = v

prop = getattr(A, "myprop")

print prop
# <property object at 0x7fe1b595a2b8>
```

Now that we have obtained the property object from the class we want to access its value. Properties have three methods `fget`, `fset`, and `fdel` that provide access to the `getter`, `settter`, and `deleter` methods defined for that property.

*Since `myprop` is an instance method, we'll have to create an instance so we can call it.*

```
print prop.fget
# <function myprop at 0x7fe1b595d5f0>

print prop.fset
# <function myprop at 0x7fe1b595d668>

print prop.fdel  # We never defined a deleter method
# None

a = A()
print prop.fget(a)
#  Hello
```

Comment: `getattr(A(), 'myprop')` returns you value of the property immediately. So, `setattr` allows to invoke `setter` method of the property

Comment: This doesn't work as advertized in the case where the setter defines the return value, b/c `getattr(A, "myprop")` will see an `AttributeError`.  I've added a different/probably better answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the most general case follow this example:

```
class Foo(object):

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._spam

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, v):
        self._spam = v

foo = Foo()
# prop = foo.bar.fset('Aaaah')  # will raise an error
# if you wanna access the setter do:
type(foo).bar.fset(foo, 'Aaaah')
print(foo.bar)
```

Comment: I find this to be the most concise and clear answer.